# How to add numbers for arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to add numbers for arraylist i have a listview checkbox on I choice the items I can get numbers 1 2 3 5 25 24 and I need to add to arraylist.This image

https://ibb.co/nmOU7H

And My code

```
        String result = "";
        for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.aBoolean)

            result += p.id;

        }
```

Comment: And I need to post data like this company[1,2,3,4]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is not up to community standards yet and will be down-voted. Please edit your question to include what you've tried, the info from your comment and don't include an image.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: If you need to add numbers, why are you storing the result as a String?

Comment: @Joe C I don`t know how to add please give example

Comment: `int sum = 1 + 2`  **NB** `1` and `2` could also be `int` variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a list and add items to it,

```
List<Integer> checkedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {

   if (p.aBoolean)
       checkedList.add(p.id);

 }
```

I would suggest you work on your basics before you start coding, it will help you in such situations.

Hope this is the solution you were looking for.